# O que significam esses argumentos no comando de "git-checkout"?

Tags: git

Tenho o seguinte comando no Git para recuperar um arquivo:

```
git checkout (hash-commit)^  --(caminho-arquivo)
```

Nesse comando o que significa o `^` e `--`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

O `^` indica que você quer o *commit* um nível acima deste especificado. Ele é o mesmo que `^1`, se você quisesse 2 níveis acima usaria `^2`.

O `--` indica que você vai passar um subcomando, um argumento do que fará com o comando principal.

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/Conceptual.md).

Comment: Muito bem explicado. Obrigado !